# When distributing an Android app, Visual Studio 2019 no longer provides an option for publishing to Google Play. What's the workaround?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to publish a Xamarin.Forms app to Google Play but the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play) don't accurately reflect the current UI for Visual Studio.  According to these docs, in order to publish to Google Play, you must first change the Channel from "Ad Hoc" to "Google Play".  The docs say you do this by clicking the "back" button in the Distribute dialog.

Here's the problem:  That button does not exist, at least not in the latest version of Visual Studio.  I took a screenshot to illustrate:

[image: As you can see, this does not match what the Microsoft docs show]

As you can see, this does not match the screenshot in the Microsoft docs, which show a "Back" button that you're instructed to click on in order to navigate to the "Select Channel" dialog, which is where I need to go in order to make it a Google Play app.  Simply clicking on "Select Channel" does absolutely nothing at all.  Right-clicking anywhere only gives the option to delete and start over.  I tried that and got the same result.

My app is a fairly simple Xamarin.Android C# app with package format set to "bundle" and Dex compiler set to "d8".  Whether AOT/LLVM is enabled has no impact on this issue.  Screenshots of full Android Options below:

[image: Android Options (1/2)]

[image: Android Options (2/2)]

**What am I missing??  How do I get Visual Studio to play nice and let me select the correct channel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly even in the past to publish your App, you had to do it via Google Play Store website initally first anyway. You were able to push updates and new version after that. However, as far as I know (since I literally just published my first app 3 weeks ago), Visual Studio API that was responible for publishing the app is deprectated. You should get that error when you try to push it to Google Play. You can use the addhock option to sign the APK and push that APK directly via Google Play Console. Visual Studio doesnt support it anymore.